# Does it violate standards to have divs appear in a different order in the markup than they do on the page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am coding a responsive site, and on the desktop version I wish for the navigation to appear on the left, but on the mobile version I want it to appear below the main content. I came up with the solution at http://abbymilberg.com/layout-sample.html by adapting a well-known grid system.

A colleague says it violates standards because the divs appear in a different order visually (on the desktop version) than they do in the markup. He seems unable to provide which standard this violates, though. I understand that it goes against traditional EXPECTATIONS from an age where all sites were desktop based, but can anybody provide me with a concrete example of what section of what standard (508, WC3, etc) this actually violates? I'm not interested in discussion of whether you think it's a good practice, just whether it violates a definitive standard. Thanks.

Comment: No, there are no standards being violated. You can reorder to your heart's content; very few users are ever going to read the HTML and then be detrimentally affected by the rendered DOM/visual content being out-of-sync with the HTML source.

Comment: the order of divs don't matter compared to rendered so no standards are been violated.  What does matter is the order of divs for the type of content example try the site on a lynx browser does it make sense on there

Comment: There is actually a new standard called flexbox that explicitly supports re-ordering elements so that they're in a different order visually than in the markup: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/#order-property

Comment: Does this affect how a screen reader will read the page?

Comment: @DavidB I'd suggest Abby fires up a screen reader to find out! The easiest way is probably to fire up VoiceOver on an Apple Mac or iOS product.

Comment: Thanks guys. The div in question (the one that appears on the left on desktops and below the main on mobile devices) is secondary nav, so I was just going to put a skip link in for screen reader purposes.

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion: this is a great script to handle relocations based on media-queries: [relocate.js](https://github.com/edenspiekermann/minwidth-relocate), more info [on their blog](http://www.edenspiekermann.com/en/blog/responsive-javascript-helpers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not, as far as I am aware, violate any documented standards. In terms of source ordering, it's generally better to have to document make sense to the user without script or styling applied. After all you ultimately have no real control over how it might render for them!

As to whether it's actually a good idea in practise, you'd need to conduct some user testing and find out. I for one would be interested to see the results!

Answer (score 1):

Semantically and accessibility speaking your colleague is right. Because if you strip down the css, the arrangement of the divs won't make sense since most codes for navigation is on the header/top part of the code.

Can you provide us the code and a screenshot?

Comment: … which could easily be “fixed” by having a “jump to navigation” link at the top.

Comment: Yep. If its really a concern :)

Comment: Yes I was going to put a skip to nav link in there.

Answer (score 0):

This does not violate any document standards in any way.

Document standards are a set of rules to follow, there are no "rules" for how you arrange your website layout.  So semantically, syntactically and technically, no you are not violating any rules.

This may however, NOT be considered "best practice".  Best practices aren't really rules, they are guidelines to help you make your site the best that it could be.  I'm not sure that this would be considered best practice on the basis that an arguement could be made that... If your layout is so odd that you have lots of content falling before the MAIN content of your site, that since bots read left to right top to bottom, this could hurt your search rankings in that it makes it harder for google to understand what your page is about.